# Обработка ответа Yes/No в Batch

Tags: bat

Пишу пакетный файл для удаления каталога вместе с файлами, возник следующий вопрос. Предположим, есть следующий код:

```
ECHO Сейчас будет удалён каталог %1
RMDIR "%1" /s
ECHO Операция выполнена!
```

Для подтверждения удаления в консоль выводится предложение либо подтвердить удаление через клавишу Y, либо прервать операцию через N. **Могу ли я как-либо запомнить выбор пользователя и в зависимости от этого выполнять набор определённых команд** (хочу, чтобы при ответе N выводилось сообщение об отмене операции)? Заранее благодарю!

Comment: *Могу ли я как-либо запомнить выбор пользователя* Ввод пользователя, запрошенный командой RMDIR - нет. Но ничто не мешает запросить в переменную (`SET /P`) и использовать введённое значение.

Answer (score 0):

Можно только заглушить стандартный запрос и создать свой:

```
ECHO Сейчас будет удалён каталог %1

CHOICE /C YN /M "Вы уверены? "

IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1 (
    RMDIR "%1" /S /Q
    ECHO Операция выполнена!
) ELSE IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 2 (
    ECHO Операция отменена.
)
```